# How to enlarge a tensor(duplicate value) in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am new in TensorFlow. I am trying to implement the global_context extraction in this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.04579, which is actually an average pooling over the whole feature map, then duplicate the 1x1 feature map back to the original size. The illustration is as below

[image]

Specifically, the expected operation is following.
input: [N, 1, 1, C] tensor, where N is the batch size and C is the number of channel
output: [N, H, W, C] tensor, where H, W is the hight and width of original feature map, and all the H * W values of output are the same as the 1x1 input.

For example,

```
    [[1, 1, 1]
1 -> [1, 1, 1]
     [1, 1, 1]]
```

I have no idea how to do this using TensorFlow. tf.image.resize_images requires 3 channels, and tf.pad cannot pad constant value other than zero.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[tf.tile](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tile) may help you

```
x = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3]]) # shape (1, 3)
y = tf.tile(x, [3, 1]) # shape (3, 3)
y_ = tf.tile(x, [3, 2]) # shape (3, 6)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    a, b, c = sess.run([x, y, y_])

>>>a
array([[1, 2, 3]], dtype=int32)
>>>b
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]], dtype=int32)
>>>c
array([[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]], dtype=int32)
```

`tf.tile(input, multiples, name=None)`
`multiples` means how many times you want to repeat in this axis
in `y` repeat axis0 3 times
in `y_` repeat axis0 3 times, and axis1 2 times

you may need to use `tf.expand_dim` first

yes it accept dynamic shape

```
x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 4])
x_shape = tf.shape(x)
y = tf.tile(x, [3 * x_shape[0], 1])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    x_ = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4]])
    a = sess.run(y, feed_dict={x:x_})
>>>a
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have found this earlier. Is it possible to use tf.tile with dynamical tensor shape? e.g., `tf.tile(input, [1, ori.get_shape()[1], ori.get_shape()[2], 1])`. I do not want to fix the the enlarging rate in the network.

Comment: The second line in your first code block should have the comment read # shape (3,3) if I am not mistaken